# How many natural solution are there for the inequality $10\leq x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5\leq 50$?

Tags: combinatorics, inequality

To my best understanding, I believe this is a "stars and bars" problem, and if the question stated $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5\leq 50$, I believe the answer would be $\binom{55}{5}$. However, when introducing a variable where we have a range that starts with $10$, I am not sure how this changes the problem.

Comment: Subtract those solutions with $x_1+\cdots + x_5 < 10$?

Comment: @lulu I think ${55 \choose 5}$ is the answer to the number of solutions to $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5 \le 50$ when the $x_i$ have to be non-negative integers.  It is then the same question as the number of solutions to $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5+x_6 = 50$

Comment: @Henry  Ah, you are absolutely right.  I have already deleted my inaccurate comment.

Comment: @peterwhy  Absolutely.  My error, now deleted.

Comment: @peterwhy, When I did the work, it would be (55 choose 5) - (14 choose 5). However, what would this look like in terms of (x choose y) because I believe (41 choose 5) is incorrect.

Comment: @user17174680 Why do you believe that $\binom {55}5 - \binom {14}5$ can be simplified to $\binom {41}5$?

Comment: What conditions do you have on $x_1$, $\dots$, $x_n$? Nonnegative? Positive? Increasing? Non-decreasing?

Comment: Is zero allowed as a value?  the question uses the word "natural" which makes me think perhaps each number must be at least 1.

Comment: @peterwhy this was just my first intuition of the question when thinking about how this could be simplified which is just to subtract the 55 and 14 and leave the 5 because we have x1 to x5. However, (55 choose 5) - (14 choose 5) and (41 choose 5) will give two different answers.

Comment: @Taladris the only condition given is that we are working with natural numbers.

Comment: @WW1 In this question, it was clarified that 0 is considered a natural number (despite in terms of definition it's incorrect).

Comment: Peterwhy has done an amazing job of helping to solve this problem. All that is necessary is to figure out how I can reduce (55 choose 5) - (14 choose 5).

Comment: Don't expect to be able to reduce the expression you have, the answer is 3476759

Comment: While it may be true that $\dfrac{55}{5}-\dfrac{14}{5}=\dfrac{41}{5}$ that is no reason to bring up $\binom{41}{5}$.  That number has nothing to do with your problem here.  It is laughable to think that $\binom{a}{k}-\binom{b}{k}=\binom{a-b}{k}$.  The closest to this we get is $\binom{n}{k}-\binom{n-1}{k}=\binom{n-1}{k-1}$ far from your proposed $\binom{1}{k}$.  Do remember that binomial coefficients *are not the same as fractions*...  As stated elsewhere, the most simplified your final answer will be will be as you already have, or in its fully evaluated form.

Comment: In your question, you should explicitly state that the natural numbers are defined as the nonnegative integers since some mathematicians define the natural numbers to be the positive integers.